# C# Noob help : if variableis equal to a specfic string

Tags: c#

recently started C# so forgive me, but I'm attempting to compare a input variable to a string for an if statement and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Console.WriteLine("Attack or Defend? (A/D): ");
choice = Console.ReadLine();

if (choice == "A")
{
    MonsterHealth = MonsterHealth - PlayerAttack;
    PlayerHealth = PlayerHealth - MonsterAttack;
}
if (choice == "D")
{

    PlayerHealth = PlayerHealth - MonsterAttack / 2;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to be working"

Comment: You aren't really helping yourself with your question. Have you tried doing any debugging? If so what have you tried? Have you considered things like case? white space characters etc?

Comment: `doesn't seem to be working` is not a real question.  Normally a question would ask something and also end with a question mark.  You have done neither.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the first `if` block, what is the value of `choice`? What is the value of `choice == "A"` ?

Comment: press capital "A" and then the enter key. That should trigger your code.

Comment: Never mind, I explained this really badly, sorry about that, but I have solved my silly problem. Thank you for those who commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparison is case-sensitive in c#.

```
if (choice.ToUpper() == "A")
{
...
}
```